Laravel Horizon - Jobs in queue take much longer to complete when under load even though CPU/mem resources are abundant
Let me start off by saying that I am no PHP or Laravel expert, but a just a humble Engineer trying to figure out why Laravel Horizon job runtime spikes when a large influx of jobs is observed. Since we rely on Horizon Queues for a lot of our operations, unfortunately this is causing our application to come to a CRAWL when we are under heavy load.
Setup

PHP version 8.2

Laravel version 10.10

Horizon version 5.2 powered by Redis


We use K8s (GKE) to spawn "Worker Pods" which run the horizon:work processes. Each worker pod has 12Gi of memory and 3 CPUs. When load is high, our first reaction is to spawn more worker pods, which in turn spawns more worker processes. My understanding is that this should cause the jobs to be worked off faster, since now there are more workers to processes them, but my understanding of this could be incorrect.
Here is the output of ps -eo pid,comm,lstart,etime,time,args when run inside one of these "Worker  Pods":
php artisan horizon
php artisan horizon:supervisor <my-pod-name>:supervisor-rabbit redis --workers-name=default --balance=simple --max-processes=15 --min-processes=1 --nice=1 --balance-cooldown=3 --balance-max-shift=5 --parent-id=7 --auto-scaling-strategy=time --backoff=0 --max-time=0 --max-jobs=0 --memory=128 --queue=rabbitmq --sleep=3 --timeout=120 --tries=1 --rest=0
php artisan horizon:work redis --name=default --supervisor=<my-pod-name>:supervisor-rabbit --backoff=0 --max-time=0 --max-jobs=0 --memory=128 --queue=rabbitmq --sleep=3 --timeout=120 --tries=1 --rest=0
php artisan horizon:work redis --name=default --supervisor=<my-pod-name>:supervisor-rabbit --backoff=0 --max-time=0 --max-jobs=0 --memory=128 --queue=rabbitmq --sleep=3 --timeout=120 --tries=1 --rest=0
php artisan horizon:work redis --name=default --supervisor=<my-pod-name>:supervisor-rabbit --backoff=0 --max-time=0 --max-jobs=0 --memory=128 --queue=rabbitmq --sleep=3 --timeout=120 --tries=1 --rest=0
php artisan horizon:work redis --name=default --supervisor=<my-pod-name>:supervisor-rabbit --backoff=0 --max-time=0 --max-jobs=0 --memory=128 --queue=rabbitmq --sleep=3 --timeout=120 --tries=1 --rest=0
php artisan horizon:work redis --name=default --supervisor=<my-pod-name>:supervisor-rabbit --backoff=0 --max-time=0 --max-jobs=0 --memory=128 --queue=rabbitmq --sleep=3 --timeout=120 --tries=1 --rest=0
php artisan horizon:work redis --name=default --supervisor=<my-pod-name>:supervisor-rabbit --backoff=0 --max-time=0 --max-jobs=0 --memory=128 --queue=rabbitmq --sleep=3 --timeout=120 --tries=1 --rest=0
php artisan horizon:work redis --name=default --supervisor=<my-pod-name>:supervisor-rabbit --backoff=0 --max-time=0 --max-jobs=0 --memory=128 --queue=rabbitmq --sleep=3 --timeout=120 --tries=1 --rest=0
php artisan horizon:work redis --name=default --supervisor=<my-pod-name>:supervisor-rabbit --backoff=0 --max-time=0 --max-jobs=0 --memory=128 --queue=rabbitmq --sleep=3 --timeout=120 --tries=1 --rest=0
php artisan horizon:work redis --name=default --supervisor=<my-pod-name>:supervisor-rabbit --backoff=0 --max-time=0 --max-jobs=0 --memory=128 --queue=rabbitmq --sleep=3 --timeout=120 --tries=1 --rest=0
php artisan horizon:work redis --name=default --supervisor=<my-pod-name>:supervisor-rabbit --backoff=0 --max-time=0 --max-jobs=0 --memory=128 --queue=rabbitmq --sleep=3 --timeout=120 --tries=1 --rest=0
php artisan horizon:work redis --name=default --supervisor=<my-pod-name>:supervisor-rabbit --backoff=0 --max-time=0 --max-jobs=0 --memory=128 --queue=rabbitmq --sleep=3 --timeout=120 --tries=1 --rest=0
php artisan horizon:work redis --name=default --supervisor=<my-pod-name>:supervisor-rabbit --backoff=0 --max-time=0 --max-jobs=0 --memory=128 --queue=rabbitmq --sleep=3 --timeout=120 --tries=1 --rest=0
php artisan horizon:work redis --name=default --supervisor=<my-pod-name>:supervisor-rabbit --backoff=0 --max-time=0 --max-jobs=0 --memory=128 --queue=rabbitmq --sleep=3 --timeout=120 --tries=1 --rest=0
php artisan horizon:work redis --name=default --supervisor=<my-pod-name>:supervisor-rabbit --backoff=0 --max-time=0 --max-jobs=0 --memory=128 --queue=rabbitmq --sleep=3 --timeout=120 --tries=1 --rest=0
php artisan horizon:work redis --name=default --supervisor=<my-pod-name>:supervisor-rabbit --backoff=0 --max-time=0 --max-jobs=0 --memory=128 --queue=rabbitmq --sleep=3 --timeout=120 --tries=1 --rest=0

Here is what our horizon.php looks like:
        'supervisor-rabbit' => [
            'connection' => 'redis',
            'queue' => ['rabbitmq'],
            'balance' => 'simple',
            'minProcesses' => 1, //ignored on `simple`
            'maxProcesses' => 15,
            'tries' => 1,
            'nice' => 1,
            'timeout' => 120,
        ],

Problem
When large number of jobs are taking place due to increased traffic on our site, job processing times (or as horizon calls it, "runtime") go from less than 10ms to more than 1000ms for each job. During normal load periods, this is what our logs look like for these "Worker Pods":

When a large influx of jobs come in, our queues grow, and job processing time explodes to the 800-1000ms range:
We still manage to keep the total number of jobs in the horizon queue below 1,000 during the influx, but the processing time still hovers at 800-1000ms as long as we continue to get the influx.
Things we have tried/checked:

Redis is well below it's available memory

The MySQL server that we use for our app is below 80% memory utilization, and CPU is below 40% during these load periods.

These "Worker Pods" never get above 30% CPU utilization, nor is memory ever higher than 1 or 2 Gi. We have plenty of resources, why would job processing times all of the sudden increase?



Additional DB information request when under serious LOAD, please.
OS, Version?
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server?
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links.
From your SSH login root, Text results of:
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links.
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE,
top -b -n 1  for most active apps,
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage,
ulimit -a       for list of limits,
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count,
df -h  for Used - Free space by device,
df -i  for inode info by device,
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:,
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.
